# Construction of genus class fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Given a finite extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$, the genus class field $L$ is defined to be the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is a subfield of the Hilbert class field $H$ of $K$. I am trying to understand the proof of an alternative construction of $G$ in the case when $K$ is a cyclic extension with prime degree $l$ as follows.

Let $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$ be the primes in $\mathbb{Q}$ that ramify in $K$. Let $L_1, L_2, ..., L_n$ be cyclic extensions of degree $l$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $L_i$ ramifies only at $p_i$. Then $L = L_1 L_2...L_n$.

I was reading the proof in "*Construction of class Fields - Carl Herz*". The basic strategy is to associate $L$ and the $L_i$'s to norm subgroups of $K$ using class field theory and relate them. But I find it hard to comprehend and justify certain crucial claims in the proof one of which I posted on MO earlier ([Norm groups of number fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392122/norm-groups-of-number-fields)).

Can someone refer me to an alternate proof of this fact or provide some light into Carl's proof if possible?

Comment: @YCor Just edited, replaced the $G$'s with L

Comment: Herz's first name is Carl. The claim is almost obvious: by Abhyankar's Lemma, the extension in question is unramified, and adjoining any other cyclic extensions ramified at a different prime gives you a ramified extension of $K$.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Thank you for your comment. Edited Herz's name. But what if I adjoin another field ramified only at say $\mathfrak{p_1}$ and degree say $l^2$?

Comment: Then the ramification index is divisible by $\ell^2$, which survives and gives you a ramified extension of $K$.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Why should then the ramification index be divisible by $l^2$? Suppose you have $L'_1 / L_1$ unramified of degree $l$. Then $L'_1 / \mathbb{Q}$ is of ramification degree $l$ at $\mathfrak{p}_1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If $L/{\mathbb Q}$ is cyclic of degree $\ell^2$, then every prime ramifying in the cyclic subfield of degree $\ell$ will ramify completely. And since ${\mathbb Q}$ does not admit unramified extensions, there is a prime with ramification index $\ell^2$. The situation is similar in the classical Hilbert-type proofs of the theorem of Kronecker-Weber; it pays to study this proof closely.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Thanks for the clarification. I did not know the fact that every prime ramifying in the cyclic subfield of degree $l$ will ramify completely. I assumed that there could be a possibility that the extension $L/L'$ can be unramified, where $L'$ is the proper subfield (of degree $l$) of $L$ and $[L : \mathbb{Q}] = l^2$. Is that a trivial fact? I don't see that easily.

Comment: It's a standard result from the theory of Hilbert ramification groups. If the ramification index is $\ell$, the unramified extension (inertia subfield) must be at the bottom.